# Throttling javafx gui updates

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety, javafx

I receive data objects at random times at a high frequency, and need to update the JavaFX GUI with these. However, I don't want to fill the javafx event queue with a very large number of runnables (I use Platform.RunLater).

I have been thinking of how to best implement a throttling algorithm.

- Would it be best to have a separate GUIUpdater thread that check for example a blocking queue for new objects, and then sleeps for example for 30ms and then checks again, in an infinite loop? In that case, would a blocking queue be the optimal data structure? Please note I only need the latest data object and the blockingQueue is a FIFO queue and I can't seem to pick only the latest entry.
- Or - would it be better to simply just update the GUI with Platform.RunLater if nanoTime-startTime > 30ms? In that case, I don't need a separate thread to perform the Platform.RunLater-call. However - if an update is received when 30ms hasn't passed, and then no updates are received for some time, the last update will not show up in the GUI.

Any suggestions on how to design a throttling algorithm for JavaFX Platform.RunLater GUI updates in a short, efficient way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the idiom used in the [`Task`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/concurrent/Task.java) class for implementing the `updateMessage(...)` method, and other similar methods. It provides a nice, robust solution to avoid flooding the FX Application Thread:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ThrottlingCounter extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(-1);
        final Label label = new Label();
        final Thread countThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long count = 0 ;
                while (true) {
                    count++ ;
                    if (counter.getAndSet(count) == -1) {
                        updateUI(counter, label);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        countThread.setDaemon(true);
        countThread.start();

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateUI(final AtomicLong counter,
            final Label label) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String msg = String.format("Count: %,d", counter.getAndSet(-1));
                label.setText(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `AtomicLong` holds the current value to be used to update the Label. The count continually increments and updates the `AtomicLong`, but only schedules a call to `Platform.runLater(...)` if it's current value is -1. The `Platform.runLater(...)` updates the `Label` with the current value from the `AtomicLong` and flips the `AtomicLong` back to -1, indicating that it's ready for a new update.

The effect here is to schedule new calls to `Platform.runLater(...)` whenever the FX Application Thread is ready to handle them. There's no hard-coded time interval which could need tuning.

Comment: Why isn't the AtomicLong set to "-1" (indicating the gui is ready to update) after the label has been set in the platform.runlater-runnable?

Comment: @user3607022 You need to retrieve the current value and set the value to `-1` *atomically*. If you retrieved the value for displaying, then set it to `-1` after it was displayed, it's possible the other thread could set the value again in between those two: i.e. 1. UI thread retrieves the value, 2. background thread updates since value is `!=-1` no update is scheduled, 3. ui sets value to -1. In this scenario, you could "miss" that intermediate value; if it were the last thing the thread did, you would miss it permanently.

Comment: Is there an easy way to describe then exactly what updates that are dropped?

Comment: @user3607022 No: and there's no real reason to care. You're specifically updating a UI property; if the UI doesn't have time to display it, it really doesn't matter if it's not received: the end user won't notice.

Comment: I see. So in other words, the updates that are dropped are the ones that the UI won't have time to display. I think I have to contemplate a bit on how this implementation produces this result. Many thanks for your help.