# JavaFX TextArea Update Immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, javafx, javafx-2

I am using Java FX textarea and using it as to provide information for the steps going on.

Steps are as follows.
Copy a file.
Delete old file.
Copy New File.
and then copy some properties from old to new file.

This whole step starts when a button is clicked.

The problem I am facing is that text area is not being updated as soon as I use the append command.

The append command adds data and when the function terminates, I get all the text together.
I want the text area to be updated as I call the function.

In my program, the copy file operation, takes some time as it is a big file.
So in the start I display message that the operation has started.
and at the end of operation I want to display the operation has ended.

But the text area displays all these texts all together.

I read in oracle forum, that text area in FX uses a single thread hence wont display anything until the whole process is complete.

Article : https://community.oracle.com/message/9938117#9938117

Can any one suggest what should I do.?

New Edit

Okay on Button Click I am calling a function which executes the following methods.

```
  public void executeCmds(){

        createTempDirectory();
        copyConfigPropetiesFileValues();
        copyConfigProperties();
        copyYMLFile();
        copyYMLFileProperties();

        stopTomcatServer();

        deleteOldWar();
        copyNewWar();
        startTomcatServer();

        copyOldConfigFile();
        copyOldYMLFile();
 }
```

Now Each of the function is a process, which should be executed sequentially. And after each step is completed I want to update the GUI text area with a success message that this is complete.

For the I am using method as follows:

```
  public void createTempDirectory(){
         //Creating temporary directory for copying property files
         status_text_area.appendText("Trying to create a temp directory \n");
        File tempDir= new       File(tomcat_path.getText()+filePath.path_to_temp_directory);
         if(!tempDir.exists())
             tempDir.mkdirs();

    status_text_area.appendText("Created Temp directory to copy Config Files \n");

}
```

and same is with other functions. The copyWar file function and delete warfile function take time as it copies 130 MB file from a location to other.

So I want the textarea to be displayed as, 
1. Started copying file
and after some time

2. FIle copied.

But the issue is , the text area does not populate at all, until all the functions are executed.

If I try to execute these via threads, then the order of execution is not guranteed.
Please Help

Comment: Start with [*Concurrency in JavaFX*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22772379/230513).

Comment: A related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27835238/230513).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run your `executeCmds()` method in a background thread and update the text area using `Platform.runLater()`:

```
public void executeCmds(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        createTempDirectory();
        copyConfigPropetiesFileValues();
        copyConfigProperties();
        copyYMLFile();
        copyYMLFileProperties();

        stopTomcatServer();

        deleteOldWar();
        copyNewWar();
        startTomcatServer();

        copyOldConfigFile();
        copyOldYMLFile();
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

and then

```
public void createTempDirectory(){
         //Creating temporary directory for copying property files
    updateStatus("Trying to create a temp directory \n");
    File tempDir= new File(tomcat_path.getText()+filePath.path_to_temp_directory);
    if(!tempDir.exists())
        tempDir.mkdirs();

    updateStatus("Created Temp directory to copy Config Files \n");
}

// similarly for other methods

private void updateStatus(String message) {
    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        status_text_area.appendText(message);
    } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> status_text_area.appendText(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG ! Thank You So much.
This is perfect, what I wanted !  Iw ill post your answer in that oracle forum also.!

Answer (score 0):

Extending the approved response - if you need to wait for updated UI before you do anything else, use `PlatformImpl.runAndWait(Runnable runnable)`

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    yourMethod();
    PlatformImpl.runAndWait(() -> {
        methodForUI();
    });
    methodAfterUIChanged();
});
thread.start();
```

Answer (score -3):

Please can you give some code excerpt ?

I regulary make a similar mistake: concat returns the concatenate string and does not modify the string whose concat method is applied.

```
        String firstString = "txt";
        String resultString = firstString.concat(" next");
```

If your concern is really linked with thread, and if your code is close from the one you mention in the article, I suggest you copy data through a parrallel thread like 
`javafx.application.Platform.runLater(e -> {
                // Do some long operation there
            });`

Please refer to existing articles on Task and runlater:
[Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx)

Edit: as James_D mentionned, if the opeartion is really long you'd better use task. Read the article I linked to know more about the alternatives and their usage.

Comment: `Platform.runLater(...)` executes code on the FX Application Thread. You should ***never*** execute a long-running operation on the FX Application Thread.