# How to run metthods without stopping the app

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, javafx

I am doing a **GET** request by JAVA, and this take some time, I've shown a loading window, but it crashes until the **GET** request finishes.

```
@FXML
    private void recogerDatos() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Haciendo la peticion GET a " + ip + ":" + puerto);
        respuestaStruct = getRequest(); 
        for (int i = 0; respuestaStruct.isHaFallado() == false && i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("Intennto:"+i);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            respuestaStruct = getRequest(); 
        }if (respuestaStruct.isHaFallado() == true) {
            System.out.println("GET realizado correctamente.");
            writeDevice.setDisable(false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error de la peticion GET");
            mensajeError = true;
        }
        MainApp.loading.close();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In this case, is better using a Thread for execution an operation od the type Http,

with swing exist a component called SwingWorker and in JavaFX exist a component Equivalent called Task.

This is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832347/javafx-swingworker-equivalent)

Comment: Wrap your function or code that is locking up the program in something like this `new Thread(()->{ YourCodeHere }).start();`