# JavaFx bindings updates sequentially on a single thread, how to force multithreading

Tags: java, javafx

I have 4 JavaFx Text objects on UI. These 4 objects are bound to 4 different  DoubleBinding

I have a doubleProperty called price.

All the 4 DoubleBindings bind to this price property. In essence when price changes, 4 different calculations are performed using the price and 4 different fields are updated.

```
 volatilityProperty = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(priceProperty);
            }
            @Override
            protected double computeValue()
            {
            }
}
```

All this works well.

However I noticed that when the price changes, each of the DoubleBindings are invoked sequentially in a single thread and its computeValue method is invoked. Is there an option so that each of the DoubleBindings start in a new thread as soon as price changes?

I tried using Task inside the overridden computeValue of the double bindings to force multithreading- but for some reason it is taking longer to complete all the 4 calculations if task is used in each of the DoubleBindings.

Comment: `computeValue()` will only actually be invoked when the value is needed, which is typically on a rendering pulse (if a UI element is bound to the binding's value), or when `get()` or `getValue()` is invoked on the binding or on a value bound to it. What is the use case here?

Comment: That is a given on computeValue(), use case: When a price change occurs, all the 4 different double bindings are recalculated as they are bound to the price. Each calculation takes around x amount of time, the priceproperty.set() method doesn't return for 4x unit of time, I would prefer it to return after x unit of time after all the 4 calculations run in parallel, as they are independent to each other.

Comment: In that case it's probably better to use listeners that trigger a computation on a new thread (probably implemented with a `Task`), instead of bindings. You might need to deal with the possibility the price changes more frequently than the dependent values can be computed.

Comment: The basic problem here is that you haven't really stated the problem you are trying to solve. All you've said is that you have a property that is updated and four values that are dependent on it that need to be displayed in the UI (even that is something I have to interpolate). None of that actually necessitates threads at all. What is the *actual requirement* here? As stated, the solution is not to use threads at all, because nothing you have told us would require their use.

Comment: *"When a price change occurs, all the 4 different double bindings are recalculated as they are bound to the price."* This is not a true statement. Bindings are not recalculated when the property to which they are bound is set. As a consequence, *"Each calculation takes around x amount of time, the `priceproperty.set()` method doesn't return for 4x unit of time"* this is not true either.

Answer (score 2):

No.  JavaFX properties must be set in one and only one thread:  the [JavaFX application thread](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#isFxApplicationThread()).  However, you can bind to a [Service](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) that does the computation in other threads using Tasks:

```
public class VolatilityCalculator
extends Service<Double> {
    private final DoubleProperty price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public VolatilityCalculator() {
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "price");
        this.price.addListener(o -> restart());
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Double> createTask() {
        double priceForCalculations = getPrice();

        return new Task<Double>() {
            @Override
            protected Double call()
            throws InterruptedException {
                // Long-running computation code goes here.
                // That code may want to check isCancelled() periodically.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your application can:

- bind to the Service’s [value](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#valueProperty())
- bind the Service’s price property to the application’s priceProperty

Like this:

```
VolatilityCalculator volatilityCalculator = new VolatilityCalculator();
volatilityCalculator.priceProperty().bind(priceProperty);
volatilityProperty.bind(volatilityCalculator.valueProperty());
```

Obligatory note on monetary values:  `double` does not store exact values.  It’s fine if this is just a learning or school project, but commercial applications **must not** store money as `double` values, because those values can literally lose information.  [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is the recommended storage type for money.  Alternatively, some people recommend using an `int` or `long` which represents the price in cents or fractions of cents (or, if not cents, whatever is the smallest unit of currency for your country).

Comment: You might want `price.addListener(obs -> restart());` in the constructor, depending on exact requirements.

Comment: @James_D Good catch.  (I had planned to add that and then forgot.)

Comment: Implemented your suggestion, but it appears that my calculation takes far less time than the FX application thread to set the property. After the calculation is over, I have to use Platform.runLater to update the UI from inside the Call method. I measured the time taken to exit run method in Platform.runlater - it is taking 10x the time taken by actual calculations. The calculation takes 10uS, where as UI update takes 200uS to set 3 properties. My original problem still persists with this solution as well

Comment: If your calculations are just pure math, with no loops and no invocations of external services, you never needed a separate thread in the first place.  Consider how many calculations a modern videogame does, thirty or more times per second.  Computer math is fast.

Comment: @abacusreader Background threads should be used for _blocking_ or _long running_ tasks. In other words, background threads are for tasks that would reduce FPS or, in the worst case, make the OS think the application has become "unresponsive". A calculation that consistently takes mere microseconds to complete is not such a task.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, the issue here is that the thread which is setting the priceproperty doesn't return immediately after setting the value. It is stuck till the UI is updated, UI only updates after the calculation is performed, here the bottle neck seems to be the UI updation rather than my calculation. Another thing I noticed is with bound property objects  an external thread is able to update the UI without issues. But if task is used then this breaks, I have to use Platform.runlater or else it throws exception.

Comment: *"I noticed is with bound property objects an external thread is able to update the UI without issues"* -> Just because it appears to work, it [doesn't mean it always will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition): "A race condition can be difficult to reproduce and debug because the end result is nondeterministic and depends on the relative timing between interfering threads. Problems of this nature can therefore disappear when running in debug mode, adding extra logging, or attaching a debugger . . . It is therefore better to avoid race conditions by careful software design.".

Comment: @abacusreader The FX Application Thread is designed for the sole purpose of updating the UI. By default in JavaFX, scene rendering is throttled (so that layout calculations, etc, are not performed more often than necessary) to 60 frames per second. So it's probably not the case that "UI update takes 200uS to set 3 properties", it's almost certainly just that those updates are being queued and not executed until it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @abacusreader Consequently, *"the issue here is that the thread which is setting the priceproperty doesn't return immediately after setting the value. It is stuck till the UI is updated"* just sounds like a design flaw. If you have something you want to run frequently, don't make it wait for UI updates, and arrange for the UI to update to the latest result of your calculations (even if that means not all calculations are actually displayed). [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488280/throttling-javafx-gui-updates]) (which you have already seen) implements this.

Comment: @abacusreader If the computation takes microseconds, then *why* are you using a background thread in the first place? Also, a call to `runLater` does not block the calling thread. All that method does is put the runnable in a queue and return. So, if your thread is truly blocked until the UI is updated then you are explicitly implementing that. But are you sure it is even "blocked"? You say it takes 200 ***micro***seconds to return from `runLater`. That could simply be due to the thread-safe enqueuing. JavaFX targets 60 FPS, and 60 FPS is one frame per 16.67 ***milli***seconds.

Comment: @abacusreader Perhaps this is an _XY Problem_ and adding a [mre] to your question would help us provide you with a solution.

Comment: @slaw The background thread is fetching the data from an external source , when the thread  has new data it sets the price property, the price property is bound to few UI elements's properties. Those UI elements properties recalculate when the priceproperty change. My expectation was that the thread will return after setting the price property immediately, because to set the property stand alone take less than 1 micro second. However it doesn't return untill all the bound properties values are calculated and UI updates. I will try my best to get a working example posted.

Comment: @abacusreader In that case, using a background thread is appropriate. But 200 _**micro**seconds_ is pretty much immediate. I struggle to see how that small amount of time could be a true bottleneck. If this is a fetch-and-display thing then the time taken to update the UI is likely a non-issue. If this is a continuous real-time update thing, then you should be conflating/coalescing updates to the UI. It most cases, it is not important for the UI to display every update, just the latest update. And that's ignoring the fact that updating the UI faster than 60 FPS is basically a waste.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78101289/2189127) from @VGR is correct in terms of threading: JavaFX properties are single threaded and should only be accessed from a single thread. Any listeners on those properties, including those created by bindings, will be invoked on the same thread and consequently dependent properties should only be accessed from the same thread. In almost all cases, properties will eventually be either bound to, or used to update, properties in UI components, so that thread should almost always be the FX Application Thread.

This answer is to note that several statements in the question and comments from the OP are not true, and to provide an example showing how and when bindings’ `computeValue()` methods are invoked. Bindings are not recomputed when the property to which they are bound is set. What actually happens is that a flag is set in the binding, indicating any value is no longer valid. Only when the value is retrieved from the binding is the `computeValue()` method invoked (and only if the binding is invalid). Thus

> when the price changes, each of the DoubleBindings are invoked sequentially

is not a true statement in general, regardless of threading. When the property is set, the `set()` method returns immediately. Thus the behavior described is not caused by the bindings but by other parts of the code which are not shown.

Here is a demo, in which there are four bindings to a property, and those bindings' `computeValue()` methods take an artificially long time to execute. The timings indicate that the property's `set()` method returns immediately, and the long-running `computeValue()` methods are only invoked later.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

import java.util.function.DoubleFunction;

public class BindingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleProperty prop = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        DoubleBinding square = createSlowBinding(prop, v -> v * v);
        DoubleBinding sqrt = createSlowBinding(prop, Math::sqrt);
        DoubleBinding sin = createSlowBinding(prop, Math::sin);
        DoubleBinding cos = createSlowBinding(prop, Math::cos);

        System.out.println("Setting value:");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prop.set(42.0);
        long setTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double value = prop.get();
        long retrieveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Time taken to set: %d milliseconds%n" +
                "Time take to retrieve property: %d%n" +
                "Value: %.1f%n",
                setTime-start, retrieveTime-setTime, value);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double sqrtValue = sqrt.get();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Square root: %.4f%n" +
                "Time take to retrieve square root: %d milliseconds%n",
                sqrtValue, end-start);
    }

    private static DoubleBinding createSlowBinding(DoubleProperty prop, DoubleFunction<Double> function) {
        return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            // simulate long computation:
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double v = prop.get();
            return function.apply(v);
        }, prop);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Setting value:
Time taken to set: 0 milliseconds
Time take to retrieve property: 0
Value: 42.0
Square root: 6.4807
Time take to retrieve square root: 1005 milliseconds
```